# Can we use variable in JSONPath expressions in JSON Extracter of JMeter

Tags: json, variables, jmeter, expression

we use  jSON Path expression in JSON Extracter in like:
$.store.book[0].title

can we use a JMeter variable instead? like:
${myexpression}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can do that. I am providing a sample test which uses CSV dataset config to pick up the JSON Path Expression. Also used variable in the JSON Extractor field.
JSON Response :

```
{
  "firstName": "John",
  "lastName" : "doe",
  "age"      : 26,
  "address"  : {
    "streetAddress": "naist street",
    "city"         : "Nara",
    "postalCode"   : "630-0192"
  },
  "phoneNumbers": [
    {
      "type"  : "iPhone",
      "number": "0123-4567-8888"
    },
    {
      "type"  : "home",
      "number": "0123-4567-8910"
    }
  ]
}
```

Path Expression: `$.phoneNumbers[:1].type` which is in a CSV file.

**CSV Data sest config:**

[image]

**JSON Extractor Setting:**

[image]

**Extracted value fed to the next request:**

[image]

**Check in View Results tree listener:**

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much, this helped me a lot.